# Why doesn't my image update?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**THE CODE**

```
var back1 = {r: 206, g: 77, b: 49}
var back2 = {r: 49, g: 142, b: 66}
var back3 = {r: 66, g: 138, b: 181}
var back4 = {r: 41, g: 81, b: 148}
var back5 = {r: 206, g: 178, b: 49}
var back6 = {r: 165, g: 93, b: 165}
var back7 = {r: 24, g: 32, b: 33}
var back8 = {r: 82, g: 44, b: 115}
var back9 = {r: 24, g: 109, b: 173}
var back10 = {r: 156, g: 40, b: 49}
var back11 = {r: 214, g: 199, b: 198}
var back12 = {r: 41, g: 36, b: 82}
var PATTERN = 1;

defaultImage = "res/img/clan-badge/Pattern_" + PATTERN + ".png";
defaultBackground = back1;

var image = new Image();
image.src = defaultImage;
image.onload = main;

function main(pattern, background) {
    background = typeof background !== 'undefined' ? background : defaultBackground;
    PATTERN = pattern;
    $('#image0').attr("src", defaultImage);
    // replace red with green
    recolorImage(image, 99, 101, 99, background.r, background.g, background.b);
}

function recolorImage(img, oldRed, oldGreen, oldBlue, newRed, newGreen, newBlue) {

    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var w = img.width;
    var h = img.height;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    // draw the image on the temporary canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    // pull the entire image into an array of pixel data
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

    // examine every pixel, 
    // change any old rgb to the new-rgb
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
        // is this pixel the old rgb?
        if (imageData.data[i] == oldRed && imageData.data[i + 1] == oldGreen && imageData.data[i + 2] == oldBlue) {
            // change to your new rgb
            imageData.data[i] = newRed;
            imageData.data[i + 1] = newGreen;
            imageData.data[i + 2] = newBlue;
        }
    }
    // put the altered data back on the canvas  
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    // put the re-colored image back on the image
    var img1 = document.getElementById("image0");
    img1.src = c.toDataURL('image/png');

}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

My problem is that when I run the `main()` function. It doesn't update the image. It does update the PATTERN variable to whatever I pass into the main parameters but the html/physical image does not change even though the `PATTERN` gets updated. Is this because the code gets executed first and so it cannot update it? Because if I refresh the page it momentarily gives me the image I want but goes back to the default state as I reloaded the page.

**EXTRA**

Code improvements are much appreciated. And if you have further questions please feel free to let me know down below of what your question may be. I will try and provide the best answer for your question.

Comment: Do you have your code for recolorImage?

Comment: Yeah. Let me update the question.

Comment: You don't seem to ever put the img into the dom.

Comment: I have the image inside the html. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: You might also consider putting ``backX`` variables into an array called ``back`` and referencing them like ``back[num]``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PATTERN` does get updated but `defaultImage` does not because `defaultImage = "res/img/clan-badge/Pattern_" + PATTERN + ".png";` only runs before `PATTERN` is updated (inside `main()`)

After `PATTERN = pattern;` put `defaultImage = "res/image/clan-badge/Pattern_" + PATTERN + ".png";`.

**EDIT**

Here's my suggested update summarized:

```
var back = [
        {r: 206, g: 77, b: 49},
        {r: 49, g: 142, b: 66},
        {r: 66, g: 138, b: 181},
        {r: 41, g: 81, b: 148},
        {r: 206, g: 178, b: 49},
        {r: 165, g: 93, b: 165},
        {r: 24, g: 32, b: 33},
        {r: 82, g: 44, b: 115},
        {r: 24, g: 109, b: 173},
        {r: 156, g: 40, b: 49},
        {r: 214, g: 199, b: 198},
        {r: 41, g: 36, b: 82}
    ], // use back[0] through back[11] to reference these
    defaultImage = 'res/img/clan-badge/Pattern_1.png',
    defaultBackground = back[0];

function main(pattern, background) {
    var image = typeof pattern !== 'undefined' ? 'res/img/clan-badge/Pattern_' + pattern + '.png' : defaultImage,
        img = new Image();

    background = typeof background !== 'undefined' ? background : defaultBackground;

    img.src = image;
    img.onload = function () {
        // replace background color
        recolorImage(img, 99, 101, 99, background.r, background.g, background.b);
    };
}

function recolorImage(img, oldRed, oldGreen, oldBlue, newRed, newGreen, newBlue) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
        w = img.width,
        h = img.height;

    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    // draw the image on the temporary canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    // pull the entire image into an array of pixel data
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

    // examine every pixel, 
    // change any old rgb to the new-rgb
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
        // is this pixel the old rgb?
        if (imageData.data[i] == oldRed && imageData.data[i + 1] == oldGreen && imageData.data[i + 2] == oldBlue) {
            // change to your new rgb
            imageData.data[i] = newRed;
            imageData.data[i + 1] = newGreen;
            imageData.data[i + 2] = newBlue;
        }
    }
    // put the altered data back on the canvas  
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    // put the re-colored image back on the image
    $('#image0').attr('src', c.toDataURL('image/png'));
}
```

Basically the problem was you weren't updating the `Image` object's source, and only updating the `PATTERN` and `defaultImage`. I hope this helps you.

**ALTERNATIVES**

If I may suggest further changes though, why not create images for every background needed so you don't need the Canvas API to edit it pixel by pixel? Perhaps a path like `res/img/clan-badge/PATTERN/BACKGROUND/image.png` or something.

Another alternative would be to make the background portion of each badge transparent (since they're PNG images) and after loading the image into the DOM, just set the background color of the `<img>` through CSS to the RGB triplet from the `back` array, again avoiding use of Canvas API for pixel-by-pixel editing, like so:

```
function main(pattern, background) {
    // assuming image is transparent where background will show through
    var image = typeof pattern !== 'undefined' ? 'res/img/clan-badge/Pattern_' + pattern + '.png' : defaultImage;

    background = typeof background !== 'undefined' ? background : defaultBackground;

    $('#image0')
        .attr('src', image)
        // set background through CSS
        .css('background-color', 'rgb(' + background.r + ',' + background.g + ',' + background.b + ')');
}
```

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper Well from what you've provided I would not expect ``defaultImage`` to be updated after every function call. Does it always log "res/image/clan-badge/Pattern_1.png", or does it log other values as well? If not, then it is not updating like you think it is.

Comment: never mind. I thought it was updating. Weird maybe I was seeing things. Yeah it updates properly now. But the phsyical image still does not.

Comment: I really appreciate the time and effort that you put into this. I really like it! Thank you very much!